# Maximum likelihood geometric distribution if $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j = 0$.

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1,..,X_n$ be an i.i.d. sample of geometric(p) random variables with unknown parameter $0<p<1$. I woluld like to find the Maximum-Likelihood estimate of p.

With the pmf $P(X=k)=p(1−p)^k $  for $k∈{1,2,3,…}$ and $0<p<1$
 my result is the following:
$\hat{p}=\left( \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j} \right)$ if I assume that $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j\neq0$.
Now, my question is: what happens if $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j=0$ and what is $\hat{p}$ in this case?

Comment: You will have $\hat{p}=1$ or as close to $p$ as your precision will allow

Comment: Why is it a problem if the sum is zero? It seems to me that your calculation is problematic if the sum is $n$.

Comment: @Henry is it possible that $\hat{p}=1$ while $p\in (0,1)$? MLE is very new for me, sorry if my question is stupid.

Comment: @A.Pongrácz Oh yes, thanks for your hint!

Comment: If the sum is n, is $\hat{p}=0$?

Comment: @tommy_m If the possible values of $p$ are an interval, then it is possible that the maximum or supremum of a function of $p$ is achieved at one end of the interval, including its end point whether or not the interval is included in the interval.  This is what I was hinting at "with as close to $1$ as your precision will allow" though sadly with a typo

Comment: @Henry I'm sorry, that was a typo, too. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: so you've got prior information that $\sum x_j = 0$ ? If so, how could your samples sum up to zero if they take non-zero integer values !! You say $k \in 1,2,3 \ldots $ .. do you mean $k \in 0,1,2,3 \ldots$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose between the two formulations of the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)

- $0$ is a possible outcome with probability $p$.  If so, then $k \in \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ with $\mathbb P(X=k) = p(1-p)^k$.  The sum of $n$ iid geometric random variables can be $0$ and the maximum likelihood estimator is $\hat{p}= \dfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i}$
- $0$ is not a possible outcome.  If so, then $k \in \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ with $\mathbb P(X=k) = p(1-p)^{k-1}$.  The sum of $n$ iid geometric random variables must be at least $n$ and the maximum likelihood estimator is $\hat{p}= \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i}$

In either case, if the obervation is the lowest possible ($0$ or $n$ respectively) then the maximum likelihood estimate is $\hat{p}=1$.  I would say this even if you start with an open interval $(0,1)$; the alternative would be to say that $\hat{p}$ is arbitrarily close to $1$